# Other text tags (p, a etc) before H1 tag

Tags: seo, semantic-seo

Does it make sence to have the first text as h1 in a page? Is there any negative impact for semantic seo? For example.

I have a slider and the description of this slider is an anchor tag with a caption description.

Then come the h1 tag.

```
<a>some link</a>
<caption>some description of slider</caption>
<h1>the title of the page</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write content for Semantic SEO, we generally want all subheadings about a topic to be placed in a hierarchy. That hierarchy is largely determined based on keyword research and what logically makes sense. For example, you'd start out with content matching the intent of broad high search volume queries narrow it down as you go answering on lower search volume, long tail queries.

Koray Tuğberk GÜBÜR has a great guide to [writing for Semantic SEO](https://www.holisticseo.digital/theoretical-seo/semantic/) if you're interested in learning more.

The structure you describe seems totally fine to me, because it will not affect your ability to create a hierarchy.

```html
<a>some link</a>
<caption>some description of slider</caption>

<h1>main topic of page</h1>
    <p>the content</p>
<h2>sub topic</h2>
    <p>more content</p>
<h3>sub sub topic</h3>
```

It is of course *ideal* for the `h1` to be the title/core topic of the page with sub topics headings following an `h2, h3, h4...` pattern. However, if for some reason you started with an `h2` and continued the hierarchy `h3, h4, h5` (perhaps due to limitations of a CMS, etc), you could still achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks alot. yes that is obvios regarding the H hierarchy. I dont have enough reputation to upvote the answer.

Comment: You could accept it!